# Error in flutter: Widgets.test is giving error due to flutter_test not recognizing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

[Here widgets.test is not recognizing the flutter_test library or the library not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbpTj.png)

If you know the solution please Inform Me.

Answer (score 0):

import the class you are calling to start the app, on the widget_test.dart

Answer (score 0):

Check `flutter_test` is in the `dev_dependencies`

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```